# how to define a variable of a class type in java when the class has extends?

Tags: java, class, extension-methods, comparable

i have this class :

```
   public class FindPath<T,N extends Path<T,N>> {

    public FindPath() {
        
   // the constructor ...
    }
}
```

and the path interface:

```
public interface Path<N, P extends Path<N,P>>
            extends Iterable<N>, Comparable<Path<?,?>>
```

where T , P and N are generic types.
i want to define a variable FindPath in another class , and call it's constructor  , basically i want something like this :

```
public class TestD {

private FindPath <WNode,WNodePath extends Path<WNode,WNodePath>> Find_Path = new FindPath;

}
```

( `WNode,WNodePath`  are another classes i use in the generic types )

what am i doing wrong ? how to do this right ?

also another question :|| the `WNodePath` class is defined like so :

```
public class WNodePath implements Path<WNode, WNodePath > { .. }
```

the path interface is `Comparable` , does that mean that also `WNodePath`  is Comparable  , which means that i can use it `compareTo()` function in a priority queue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a `FindPath` reference you don't use `extends`, that's used to provide bounds (limits) on the classes it is legal to use for that type parameter. (You can use extends when you have a wildcard type parameter, but that's not relevant here, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Just say:

```
    private FindPath<WNode,WNodePath> findPath = new FindPath<>();
```

Which compiles.

Yes, `WNodePath` implements `Comparable`, transitively via `Path`.